# Does group policy install directly from the network share?

Tags: wix, group-policy

I am trying to use group policy to install an MSI.  I've been testing locally and have omnibus generated installer that has some other dynamic files (placed next to the installer) I'd like to **not be included** in the msi but present at msi install time.

My installer takes these files and if they're present, will also add them to the installation directory at install time.  This works when not using group policy.

When they are present on the share with group policy the MSI is installed but none of the other files placed next to the installer are.

My question is, does group policy copy installers to a temp directory before being installed or does it install directly from the group policy share?  I can't seem to find any documentation on what goes on under the covers during a group policy install.

Thanks in advance for any information.

Answer (score 0):

I now suspect the issue is unrelated to group policy and is actually a side effect of using shares to install.  With msiexec debug enabled, I see:

When I install an msi from the local drive:

```
MSI (c) (7C:D0) [12:45:47:562]: Original package ==> c:\our-installer-x86.msi
MSI (c) (7C:D0) [12:45:47:562]: Package we're running from ==> c:\our-installer-x86.msi
```

When I install an msi from the share:

```
MSI (c) (E8:4C) [12:36:13:532]: Original package ==> \\our-server\dir\our-installer-x86.msi
MSI (c) (E8:4C) [12:36:13:532]: Package we're running from ==> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\35a9b829.msi
```

I guess ultimately we'll need to choose a different deploy path to make this work.